# how to mime type of the url

Tags: java, cxf

I am using cxf as a webservice.It supports xml and json format output of the requested data.I want to know that if some exception has occured in my code then  i want to return him back the error code either in xml or json format.But i dont know when to give json and xml ,it depends on the requested url that user has asked.

example

@Path("/reports/ad-view/loginId/{loginId}/publisher/")

```
PublisherReports getPublisherReportsAdView(

        @PathParam("loginId") String loginId,
        @QueryParam("fromDate") String fromDate,
        @QueryParam("toDate") String toDate,
        @QueryParam("filterValue") String filterValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to detect the mime type used to make the request, then you can use the @Consumes annotation to dictate which method handles which type of request. So you could write:

```
// Called when an XML request is made
@Path("/reports/ad-view/loginId/{loginId}/publisher/")
@Consumes("application/xml")
PublisherReports getPublisherReportsAdViewXml(...
```

and:

```
// Called when a JSON request is made
@Path("/reports/ad-view/loginId/{loginId}/publisher/")
@Consumes("application/json")
PublisherReports getPublisherReportsAdViewJson(...
```

Then have each variant of the getPublisherReportsAdView() method call a common method to perform the actual processing logic but still handle exceptions differently depending on the method that gets called.

Comment: in this case i m making extra function which will increase my code size.Instead of that i can pass the query param which will tell me mimetype as xml or json.



And i dont need to know mimeType if there is no exception in my code.If everything is fine then cxf will automatically return the requested format

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach, which doesn't require additional methods, would be to add a parameter which is annotated with the @HeaderParam annotation and use that to hold the value of the 'Content-Type' request header.

e.g.:

```
PublisherReports getPublisherReportsAdView(
                @PathParam("loginId") String loginId,
                @QueryParam("fromDate") String fromDate,
                @QueryParam("toDate") String toDate,
                @QueryParam("filterValue") String filterValue,
                @HeaderParam("Content-Type") String contentType)
{
  ...
```

The value of contentType will likely also include charset information, for example: application/json; **charset=UTF-8** so you'll need to ignore that when working out if the request contained JSON or XML.

Comment: how to define headerparam in the url
can u explain little more

Comment: if i print content-type it is giving value 'null'

Comment: @HeaderParam doesn't inject a value from the URL, it takes a value from an HTTP header, with the given name, in the request. Here is the documentation for it: http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/jax-rs/1.0/javax/ws/rs/HeaderParam.html

Comment: Do you mean you don't understand, or you aren't seeing a value being injected when using @HeaderParam?

Perhpas check the HTTP request being made to be sure that the header is present?

Comment: got it.But i m not setting the header.there are two aap one aap will call another.I think @consumes will be better in this case